# Can we make user icons on review tests be random?

Tags: feature-request

I was doing some reviews of first posts earlier when I got this question as a test (with a random username, of course):

[What is the difference between using '+' (plus) and ';' (semicolon) in -exec command?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/558817/what-is-the-difference-between-using-and-in-exec-command)

I recognized @kasiya's picture from the test (it said something like user### but then with that picture), so I immediately knew it was a test.

With some of the other high rep/active users who have recognizable pictures (oli, rinzwind for example) this could be detrimental - passing tests based on pictures, not quality of the review. For the tests could we have it pull, for example, someone's [gravatar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17443/how-is-the-default-user-avatar-generated)?

Comment: Good idea, although I don't think it is strictly necessary, if you are paying enough attention to notice the user's gravatar you're probably not a robo reviewer.

Comment: Well specifically I noticed Kasiya's avatar because it WASN'T a gravatar, but that bright pink square